# Introduce tsql a datetime with a specific timezone and convert it into another one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timezone

I'm working in a procedure which takes dates from a table. In that table it exists two coloms: [Date] , [TimeZone]
Example:
`(origin table)
L   [Date] | [TimeZone]<br>
0   00:00    America/Los_Angeles<br>
1   14:00    America/Anchorage<br>
2   10:00    Europe/London<br>`
 
As you can see there are diferente times and timezones. What I would like to achieve is take each of the times and convert it to Europe/Madrid. The table destiny where the data is going to be stored after the transformation should look like:

`(Destiny table)
L  [Date] | [TimeZone]<br>
0   09:00    Europe/Madrid ( +9 hours )<br>
1   00:00    Europe/Madrid ( +10 hours ) <br>
2   11:00    Europe/Madrid ( +1 hour )<br>`

Having in mind that the dst could affect any of the timezones, of course.

I know it's a little bit tricky but any help would be great. 
Thank you very much in advance.

I tried using the **At time zone command**, but my main problen it's that i don't know how to fix the data taken as datetime variable into a specific timezone

example: 
    SELECT convert(datetime,''Jul 19 2019  9:00AM'')  AT TIME ZONE ''Central European Standard Time''

I don't know how to specify that the date ( Jul 19 2019  9:00AM )  is in the timezone of America/Los_Angeles, for example.

Comment: One way is to create a lookup table with time zones and time offsets for CST conversion and join that to your table to determine hours to add / subtract. I know its a bit of a  manual process but will work

Comment: I tried that solution also, but the problem resides in compute in which moment each of the timezones has the dst activated. It infeseable the computation , due to in that table i would have to store the start and end of each zone ( almost 592 timezone differents). That's why i want to use the commands that tsql give us.

Comment: I have no idea if you have any influence about requirements, but if you do I would try to go back and try to get all into DateTimeOffset, e.g. LA-time would then go in as 00:00 -8 of it isn't Daylight savings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the challenge you face is that you have IANA time zone identifiers (such as `'America/Los_Angeles'`) rather than Windows time zone identifiers (such as `'Eastern Standard Time'`).  For more on this, see [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) in the section titled "Time Zone Databases".

There are a few different ways you can work with IANA identifiers:

- The `AT TIME ZONE` command works with the time zones of the operating system.  Thus when you are running SQL Server on Windows it uses Windows time zone identifiers.  If instead you are running SQL Server on Linux then you can use the IANA time zone identifier directly.

  ```
  SELECT yourDateTime AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Madrid'
  ```

  Note there are *two* calls to `AT TIME ZONE` here.  The first asserts the source time zone, creating a `datetimeoffset` from the `datetime` (or `datetime2`) given.  The second converts the `datetimeoffset` to the destination time zone, resulting in a `datetimeoffset` with the local time and offset adjusted appropriately.

  The remaining approaches below assume you are running on Windows.
- You could write an external application to convert the time zone identifiers from IANA to Windows.  You could either update the existing field, or populate a secondary field.  For example, if you are writing a .NET Application, then you can use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library to translate.  Then you would run the same query as above using the corresponding Windows zones instead.  For example:

  ```
  SELECT yourDateTime AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time'
  ```
- You could import the [CLDR `windowsZones.xml`](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) file into a table.  This file contains most of the translation data between the two different time zone identifier types. You could then join to that table at time of query.
- You could use my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) package.  It's a bit old, but it still works.  This imports IANA time zone data into tables in SQL Server, and provides functions for converting.  For example:

  ```
  SELECT Tzdb.ConvertZone(yourDateTime, 'America/Los_Angeles', 'Europe/Madrid', 1, 1)
  ```
- You could do all your time zone conversions in an external application.  You could use TimeZoneConverter as shown earlier, along with the `TimeZoneInfo` class in .NET.  Or you could use [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) instead, with the IANA (aka TZDB) identifiers.  There are similar packages in other programming languages as well.